# Setting up Bonobo 5.0.0 with Windows authentication

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, bonobo

I'm trying to install Bonobo 5.0.0 on Windows 7 + IIS 7.5 with Windows authentication.

When I go to the homepage (`http://domain/bonobo`), I'm prompted for my Windows username/password and after that it redirects back to the root to look for a route called windowsAuthCallback:

```
http://domain/windowsAuthCallback?id=xxx
```

Obviously this gives me a 404 error.

I have authentication set to 'anonymous' in IIS and 'Windows' in the Bonobo web.config and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

Not sure if this is related... I have an existing Bonobo installation on the same server and I'm installing Bonobo 5 fresh as a new application. After running into the issue I described, trying to open the original Bonobo app gives me the following error:

```
Unable to find an entry point named 'sqlite3_open_interop' in DLL 'SQLite.Interop.dll'.
```

Restarting IIS resolves the issue and I can access my old Bonobo app again.

Comment: Apparently [this commit](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/commit/fb62909959c8d3c25d9e55fb737e0c7147ad4deb) solves the issue. A workaround is detailed [here](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/333), but I haven't tried it.

Comment: No dice, neither the workaround nor that commit solves the original issue of redirecting back to root.

Comment: Are you using Active Directory? Maybe the fix only works if you are. You should re-open the issue on the repo with some more details.

Comment: I committed a fix and it got pulled to master. Seems to work now.

Comment: If you want to put that in an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This commit should resolve the windowsAuthCallback redirecting to root: https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/commit/852563e2e1f969abca008b8be798c265a52f4d81

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this issue along with a link to the commit that resolves it can be found on the following page:

https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server/issues/333