# Bonobo 5.0.1 with Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, bonobo

Installed Bonobo 5.0.1 on a 2008R2 server running IIS 7.5.  Site is setup where Bonobo is the site - not an application off another site.  Everything seems to work with cookies authentication and the internal membership.  I get the same error that is in this question: [Setting up Bonobo 5.0.0 with Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33286929/setting-up-bonobo-5-0-0-with-windows-authentication)

App pool is setup with a user that has rights to the network etc.  All groups are local groups to the server.  I'm in a multi-domain environment and I have the base domain set up for the same domain the server is in.  However, most users will be coming from other domains.  Was trying to keep it simple first by using local user groups and till I understood what was happening with authentication/authorization.

When a user attempts to access the site - it returns:
bonobogit.maindomain.com/windowsAuthCallback?id=xxxxxxx

No error - just a blank screen.  favicon gets served up,etc.

Any thoughts on what I may be missing?

Comment: Forgot to add the error I found in Bonobo.Git.Server.Errors.log: w3wp.exe Error: 0 : Error occured and caught in Global.asax - System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Bonobo.Git.Server.Owin.Windows.WindowsAuthenticationHandler.AuthenticateCoreAsync()
   at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)